# Can I embed a Schema within a Schema in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
SocialProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema
  source: String
  user_id: String
  profile_url: String

UserProfileSchema  = new mongoose.Schema
    socialProfiles: [SocialProfileSchema]
```

That's my code. Is it valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes! This is valid it turns out!

Answer (score 0):

That code will create an embedded documents array of SocialProfiles within UserProfiles -- http://mongoosejs.com/docs/embedded-documents.html